# Recursively generation of vectors

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have a problem with a comprehensive understanding of recursion. I will copy the code and then we'll tell you what I learned from the whole thing and i will ask you my question.

```
static void generate(int index, int[] vector) {
        if (index < 0) {
              print(vector);
        } else {
              for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    vector[index] = i;
                    generate(index - 1, vector);
              }
        }
  }

  static void print(int[] vector) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vector));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        int size = 2;
        int[] vector = new int[size];
        generate(size - 1, vector);
  }
```

At the beginning the index is 1 and after the for loop at position 1 the program record 1 after that the method is called recursively and the index became 0. On position 0 the program record 1. After that the program check the value of index and it is -1 (thats why it prints the first array). After that the index is still null and the program records only on position null but at position one the value is 1 without iteration. I can not understand how the program know that in position one the value is 1 ?

Comment: That would be exactly what I expected. The first recursion advances after the second has passed the for loop. I suggest using a debugger and step it through.

Comment: I`m using debugger but its difficult for me to understand it.

Comment: Maybe add what would be your expected behavior. I have hard times understanding what it is that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of recursion and iteration may make it a bit hard to understand. You can always debug it in order to find out what it is doing.

First, `generate (1, vector)`.
Then, in the iteration, `vector[1] = 1` is called, and `generate (0,vector)` is called.

In this call, the iteration is called again, and when `i=1` is set, `vector[0] = 1` is set. generation(-1 ,vector) is called, the recursion breaks, and the content of the array is printed: [1, 1]

Next iteration: `i=2;` `vector[0]=2` prints: [2,1]
Then: [3,1],[4,1],[5,1]

Back in `generate (1, vector)`, `vector[1] = 2` is set , and and `generate (0,vector)` is called ...  and so ...

Comment: I`ve finally understand it. When the first 5 vectors are generated the value for position [1] is always 1 because the value is in stack and it will be 1 until the program go back to it.